# Find the limit of sequence $\left(\frac{u_n}{n}\right)$

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence $(u_n)$ defined by: $u_1>0; u_{n+1}=u_n+\frac{n}{u_n}$ and $n=1,2,....$
Prove the convergency and find the limit of sequence $\left(\frac{u_n}{n}\right)$

I have tried finding the limit by proving $(\frac{u_n}{n})$ is monotonic and bounded sequence. By induction, I knew that $\frac{u_{n+1}}{n+1}< \frac{u_n}{n}$ when $n\geq 2$. It isn't correct with $n=1$. I'm so confused because I don't know how to continue.
Does anyone have any ideas? Thank in advance!

Comment: How did you prove $\frac{u_{n+1}}{n+1}< \frac{u_n}{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

The following is inspired by [A limit problem about $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{n}{a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493528/a-limit-problem-about-a-n1-a-n-fracna-n) and by [Sequence limit](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1566064p9593918), but not identical.

$$
 u_{n+1}^2 = u_n^2 + 2n + \frac{n^2}{u_n^2} \ge u_n^2 + 2n
$$
implies that
$$ \tag{*}
 u_n^2 \ge n(n-1) 
$$
for all $n$. Then
$$
 \frac{u_{n+1}}{n} - \frac{u_n}{n-1} = \frac{u_n}{n} + \frac{1}{u_n} - \frac{u_n}{n-1}
= \frac{1}{u_n} - \frac{u_n}{(n-1)n} \le 0
$$
for $n \ge 2$, so that the sequence $u_n/(n-1)$ is decreasing and therefore convergent. It follows that
$$
 L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_n}{n}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_n}{n-1}
$$
exists as well, and $(*)$ implies that $L \ge 1$.

It remains to determine the value of $L$. Here we can use the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$
L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_n}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{(n+1)-n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{u_n} = \frac 1 L
$$
and therefore $L=1$.

Comment: "$u_n< n+1$" for all $n\geq 2$- it seems to be incorrect. I supposed that $u_1=0.5$ then $u_2=4.5>2+1$

Comment: @Analyn_a: Please let me know if anything is still unclear.